# Naive question: What makes a vector field a nonvanishing vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry

The notation I'm using is such: Let $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ be a vector field where $M$ is a manifold. Then $X(m)\in T_mM$. What does it mean for $X$ to be *nonvanishing*?

Do I need $X(m)=0$ (zero vector) for some $m$, or is it that $\langle X(m), m \rangle =0$ (scalar 0) for some $m$ [ for example if $M=S^n$], where $m$ can be viewed as a vector $\overrightarrow{Om}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A nonvanishing vector field means it is never zero at any point.

Comment: Thank you!! - I presume you're saying the first criteria that $X(m)\neq 0$ for all $m$ in $M$.